# Problem with roc curve in scikit - DecisionTreeClassifier() , ExtraTreeClassifier()

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a question to you (maybe i don't understand something). My target value is binary (Yes/No). I make a prediction using scikit learn for few classiefiers, and plot the roc curve. Everything look good except for roc curves for DecisionTreeClassifier() , ExtraTreeClassifier(). I get something like this:
[image]

In other classiefiers i get something similar to this:
[image]

I tried all scikit function to display roc curve and i get the same plot. Could you show me the path how can i "improve" my model or plot? My code for DecisionTreeClassifier():

```
model3 = make_pipeline(preprocessor, DecisionTreeClassifier())
model3[:-1].get_feature_names_out()
m=model3[:-1].get_feature_names_out()
model3 = model3.fit(data_train, target_train)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
plot_tree(model3.named_steps['decisiontreeclassifier'], fontsize=10, node_ids=True,
feature_names=m, max_depth=5)

cm3 = confusion_matrix(target_test, y_pred3, normalize='all')
cm3_display = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm3).plot()
plt.xlabel('Klasa predykowana – wynik testu')
plt.ylabel('Klasa rzeczywista')
plt.show()

RocCurveDisplay.from_estimator(model3, data_test, target_test)
plt.show()

RocCurveDisplay.from_predictions(target_test, y_pred3)
plt.show()

model3_probs = model3.predict_proba(data_test)
model3_probs = model3_probs[:, 1]
model3_fpr, model3_tpr, _ = roc_curve(target_test, model3_probs)
roc_auc = metrics.auc(model3_fpr, model3_tpr)
display = metrics.RocCurveDisplay(fpr=model3_fpr, tpr=model3_tpr,
roc_auc=roc_auc,estimator_name='example estimator')
display.plot()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many examples are included in your test data? Possibly only three? What the curve looks like will depend also on the number of samples that you used for testing. Using more samples will produce a more similar output to your expectations.

For clarification: The curve is produced by increasing a cut-off threshold for your predictions and plotting the false positive and true positive rates for an increasing value of this threshold (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Curves_in_ROC_space)). If you only include very few samples, your curve only has very few points to plot. Thus, it looks just like yours.

Edit from the comments: The thing that happened here is, that your tree is filled completely by your data due to the unlimited complexity of the tree (e.g. when not setting a max_depth or min_samples for each leaf). This means that all leafs (also at test-time) are pure and your predictions have only probabilities of 0 and 1, nothing in between. Thus, since the threshold does not matter, your ROC only changes once from (0,0) to the point determined by the (fpr,tpr) in the test-set and to (1,1), looking like your curve. This can be circumvented by using a RandomForest (introducing randomness) or restricting the decision tree in order to get probabilities in between 0 and 1 by counting what's in the leaf. A related thread can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105760/how-we-can-draw-an-roc-curve-for-decision-trees).

Nevertheless, there is nothing wrong with your plot, if pure leafs are okay for you!

Comment: I use 15 numerical columns and 10 categorical. I encode them by hot encoder in pipeline. Number of rows for training is up to 50 000 and for test up to 20 000. What do you mean by "examples"?

Comment: The "examples" I ment were the 20k samples used for testing (aka. the rows in data_test). If it would have been only very few samples, it could have explained the curve.

Another thing to test: You haven't specified a max_depth for the decision tree. It could be that your tree gets so big that it (over!)fits all 50k samples of the training data and in the leaves are only single samples most of the time at test-time. Since the ROC needs the predict_prob function this could lead to nearly only 0 or 1 probabilities and thus this odd curve. You could try to truncate the tree with max_depth.

Comment: One way to check for what I mean is to look at "model3_probs". If it consists only of 0s and 1s, the threshold only swaps once (this is the tp and fp ratio that you see) and thus you get your odd looking graph. Going down with depth or requiring min_samples in the leaves will "fix" that, giving you "real" probabilities and thus a nicer looking curve.

Comment: Yes, you are correct i change the parameters in classifier. Now it "looks better". So i need to work more, and improve my model. Thank you!!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).